# ffmpeg pulseaudio output options (device)

Tags: ffmpeg, pulseaudio

I need to use some of the [documented pulseaudio options for ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#pulse-1) such as the device.  The example from the documentation works, but only sets the stream name:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -f pulse "stream name"
```

I have a sink named playback-device which I want to use.  Based on the doc and googling, I tried various options to specify the device.  They all give errors (or don't work):

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -f pulse -device playback-device
# At least one output file must be specified

ffmpeg -i INPUT -f pulse -device=playback-device
# Unrecognized option 'device=playback-device'.  Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

ffmpeg -i INPUT -f pulse device=playback-device
# Plays to default device not the specified one

ffmpeg -i INPUT -device playback-device -f pulse
# At least one output file must be specified
```

The device is there:

```
$ pactl list short sinks | grep playback
3       playback-device module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 48000Hz       IDLE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> ffmpeg -i INPUT -f pulse -device playback-device
> # At least one output file must be specified
> ```

This tells you that you are missing the argument which you had in your working example (`ffmpeg -i INPUT -f pulse "stream name"`). So the correct command is:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -f pulse -device playback-device "stream name"
```

Of course you can replace `"stream name"` with anything that doesn't look like an option.

Comment: So the stream name parameter is mandatory, and when not present the error message refers to it as an "output file".    And it can also be specified using -stream_name.  It would be very helpful if the ffmpeg documentation made any of this clear!